# How to link to an xxx.dll when the provider only ships it with an xxx.lib and you are using MinGW-w64 and not MSVC?

Tags: dll, linker, mingw, dynamic-linking, mingw-w64

**Firebird** and **Boost** communities only provide the **xxx.lib** for their pre-built **xxx.dll** binaries,

and I am using **MinGW-w64 v7.0.0** with **GCC v8.1.0**,

and this last one expects a **libxxx.a** file containing all the **xxx.dll** function symbols to link with.

For **Boost**, I can build it from the source code for **MinGW-w64** (though I still prefer using the pre-built ones, because the build process for big toolkits like this one takes forever).

As for **Firebird**, it is not buildable using **MinGW-w64** at all, except if patched, and I can't guarantee that the patched source files will produce a safe **fbclient.dll** for production.

And I have heard that newer versions of **MinGW-w64** accept **direct linking** to a **.dll**,

Is this true? is it just **MinGW-w64 .dll**s, only **C .dll**s or including **C++** ones, or any kind of a **.dll** including **MSVC** ones.

You may say: "**Why don't I just use Msys2!?**"

1. **Msys2** is a patch based software, and I have seen a lot of libraries like **libcurl** that are still not purely static (the static version, the **.a** one not the **.dll.a** one) still depends on one or more external **.dll**s (not the system ones).
2. **Msys2** is **Dwarf2** based exception handling and I am using the **sjlj** one.
3. **Msys2** uses a very recent tool-chain **v9.2.0** and libraries like **winpthreads**, **libwinpthread** and **zstd** that are no longer supported in **Windows XP** (**Windows XP!? YES**, more of my clients are still using it), so I have to downgrade the tool-chain.

So, what are my options, for linking here?

TIA.

Comment: You should be able to link C dlls of any compiler, but it will not work for C++ dlls.

Comment: Can you provide the link from which you have download mingw-w64 and gcc?

Comment: @Biswapriyo Yeah, sure. This is the online installer http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/Toolchains%20targetting%20Win32/Personal%20Builds/mingw-builds/installer/mingw-w64-install.exe/download. And this is the files directory where you can chose offline packages: http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows DLLs can not be linked with a executable programs. For linking, we have
to create a export library for mingw-w64. This answer assumes you have already
install mingw-w64 in your development environment and mingw-w64 tools is
accessible in command line.

The export library can be created from DLL or LIB file. Here the procedure is 
followed from DLL file. Open command prompt. Assume the DLL is `foo.dll`.

- Generate Export Definition file with `gendef`:

```
gendef.exe foo.dll
```

This command takes `foo.dll` and generates `foo.def`.

- Generate export library with `dlltool`:

```
dlltool.exe --dllname foo.dll --input-def foo.def --output-lib libfoo.a
```

This command takes `foo.def` and `foo.dll` and generates `libfoo.a`. Remember
the export library `libfoo.a` name starts with `lib-` but at the time of
compiling/linking the linking option should be `-lfoo` in case of GCC.
The generated export library `libfoo.a` only contains the symbols that are
exported from the DLL, it can not be used for static linking.

The procedure does not depend if the host is MSYS2 or MinGW-w64 or cross
compiler in any GNU/Linux distribution.

### Further Readings

- [mingw: How to create an import library for a DLL using MinGW](http://mingw.org/wiki/CreateImportLibraries)
- [mingw-w64: Generating an import library for a DLL](https://sourceforge.net/p/mingw-w64/wiki2/Answer%20generation%20of%20DLL%20import%20library/)
- [dlltool manpage](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/dlltool.1.html)

Comment: I will try it and come back. I will also try the direct linking to a DLL using ld.exe, see "direct linking to a dll" section here https://www.sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.34/ld/WIN32.html